# Rails: Not all associated user posts appear in list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Current there are three models: `users`, `teachers` and `posts`.

I was able to make associations so that teachers can see posts of just their users, with these associations (thanks to everyone for your help so far):

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :posts, through: :users
def user_posts
    Post.where(id: users.map(&:id))
  end
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Also, Users: `belongs_to :teacher, has_many :posts`
While Posts: `belongs_to :user`

The goal is to let teachers see their users posts. However, it is only partially working- the bug is that **when a teachers views his users’ posts, only a few posts show up.**

For example, user Corey has made 2 posts. But his teacher Mr. Feeney only can see 1 of those posts. I’ve tried reseting the DB and creating new entries but the problem persists. Does anyone know why this may be and any potential solutions?

Teachers controller

```
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_teacher, only: [:index]

def index
 @posts = @findteacher.user_posts
 @teachers = Teacher.all
end

def show
  @teacher = Teacher.find_by_username(params[:id])
end

private
  def find_teacher
    @findteacher = current_teacher
  end
end
```

Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def self.find_for_authentication(conditions)
  conditions = ["username = ? or email = ?", conditions[authentication_keys.first], conditions[authentication_keys.first]]
  # raise StandardError, conditions.inspect
  super
end

def index
    @users = User.all
end

def show
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
end
end

 def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Posts controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json

def index
  if params[:user_id]
    @posts = Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
  else
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build

  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :username, :Duration, :Rating)
    end
end
```

Teachers index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1><%= current_teacher.username %>  student posts</h1>

Studio Posts for <%= current_teacher.username %> (Your id: <%= current_teacher.id %>)

<p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>UserID</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Created At</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Rating</th>
      <th>TeacherID</th>

      <th colspan="3"></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>

      <tr>
        <td><%= post.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to post.user.username, post.user %></td>

        <td><%= post.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= post.Duration %></td>
        <td><%= post.Rating %></td>
        <td><%= post.user.teacher_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Schema (just parts of it)

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.integer  "teacher_id"
end

...

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "Duration"
    t.text     "Rating"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text     "username"
...
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.integer  "teacher_id"
  end
```

Comment: Please show the post data that isn't working, e.g., the db rows

Comment: Based on what you have, looks like each user would only have one teacher?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this method in the Teacher class

```
def user_posts
  Post.where(id: users.map(&:id))
end
```

The query should be `Post.where(user_id: users.map(&:id)`

Probably Corey has an `id=1` and he posted 2 posts one with `id=1` and one with `id=2` but both have `user_id=1`. Your original query does this `Post.where(id: [1])` which results in one post only displayed. But the correct query should be `Post.where(user_id: [1])` which returns all posts by the user.